# What is the difference between Application.Calculate and Application.CalculateFull?

Tags: excel, vba

What is the difference between `Application.Calculate` and `Application.CalculateFull`?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195517.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194064.aspx

Looking at this I don't know if they may result in different results or their scope or efficiency is different.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`Calculate` calculates only new, changed and volatile formulas.

`CalculateFull` calculates **all** formulas regardless. As a general rule, this will therefore be slower.

`CalculateFullRebuild` calculates all formulas and rebuilds the entire calculation dependency tree. This will be the slowest of all.