# Excel VBA Application.Calculate does not work but Ctrl+Alt+F9 does

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an unusual problem with Excel 2013. I have a VBA script to pull data from SQL and generate HTML files then import those HTML files into tabs followed by a recalculate call for formulas that are dependent on the data generated prior.

Here is the basic structure:

```
Sub RefreshData()

Task1 ' run 1st query and generate HTML file
Task2 ' run 2nd query and generate HTML file
.
.
.
Taskn ' run nth query and generate HTML file
RefreshDataInTabs ' refresh all tabs with generated HTML files
Calculate_AllOpenWorkbooks ' calculate all formulas that depend on data obtained in Tasks above

End Sub
```

Here is the call to calculate...

```
Sub Calculate_AllOpenWorkBooks()

Application.Calculate

End Sub.
```

So everything works as expected until call to Calculate_AllOpenWorkBooks. Cells with formulas don't update. "Automatic" Workbook Calculation is selected in the Calculation options windows in Excel Options. Manual Data -> Refresh All doesn't work **BUT** Ctrl+Alt+F9 does!

Comment: How about `application.CalculateFull`

Answer (score 3):

After many attempts to solve the problem I ended up using

```
SendKeys "{F9}"
```

There is a `10 ms` delay, but it works and you can use it in code.

You can even do `SendKeys "^%{F9}"` for `Ctrl+Alt+F9`, if you want.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. However, SendKeys "{F9}" is problematic for me. I am performing this command within a loop and I want to obtain the updated value of a cell after each recalculation of the worksheet. But Excel only remembers the initial value of the cell I am interested in and copies that same value at each iteration rather than its updated value. Is this something you encountered as well?

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub Calculate_AllOpenWorkBooks()

Application.CalculateFull

End Sub
```

and if you need the application to wait:

```
Sub Calculate_AllOpenWorkBooks()

Application.CalculateFull

If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
DoEvents
Else: End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Something is preventing CalculationState to change to xlDone. My code remains at "Pending"

Comment: Are you able to share a minimal example? I would suggest making a copy of the workbook and then one by one deleting parts of it you suspect are calculation-intensive, re-trying the Sub each time. This might help you workout what is calculating forever

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues where on some client's machines `Application.Calculate` just doesn't refresh the results (very randomly) in a loop. I've taken ideas from above and from [Rory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37461126/6822528) to come up with the below approach.

```
Function calculateUntilCalculationStateIsDone() As Boolean
    ' A very paranoid calculation routine to avoid Excel bugs as in
    ' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44378969/excel-vba-application-calculate-does-not-work-but-ctrlaltf9-does
    ' Calculate until the calculation state is xlDone
    ' First try Application.Calculate 10 times
    ' Then try Application.CalculateFull 10 times
    ' Then try Application.CalculateFullRebuild 10 times
    ' If not done, set calculation options to automatic, and do events until done.
    '   Give up after 1 minute to avoid an infinite loop
    ' Set the calculation option back to what it was before after loop
    '
    ' Returns:
    '   True if calculation was successful
    '   False if calculation was unsuccessful
    
    calculateUntilCalculationStateIsDone = True ' calculation is done unless proven otherwise
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 10
        If Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then Exit Function
        Application.Calculate
    Next i
    
    For i = 1 To 10
        If Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then Exit Function
        Application.calculateFull
    Next i
    
    For i = 1 To 10
        If Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then Exit Function
        Application.CalculateFullRebuild
    Next i
    
    Dim currentCalculationOption As Variant
    currentCalculationOption = Application.Calculation
    ' store current calculation option
    
    Dim Time As Date
    Time = Now()
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    ' Set to automatic recalculation
    
    Do Until Application.CalculationState = xlDone
        ' Wait for Excel to finish calculating
        DoEvents
        
        If Now() - Time > TimeValue("0:01:00") Then
            ' give up after 1 minute of trying to avoid infinite loop
            Application.Calculation = currentCalculationOption
            calculateUntilCalculationStateIsDone = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Loop
    
    ' Set the calculation option back to what it was before
    Application.Calculation = currentCalculationOption
    
End Function
```

I've tested the runtime on a loop that took 1m55s, this increased it to 1m57s, which was not a big loss in performance (the impact would depend on the complexity of the underlying Excel calculations).

I made it a function that returns whether the calculation was successful or not, so the caller sub / function can add a warning / raise an error if not as appropriate for your application.