# VBA Script Not Copying NOW() Properly

Tags: vba, excel

I never program in Excel/VBA, so any assistance is appreciated.

My script basically works, except it seems to be pasting the data from the Last time it copied rather than the current data.

First, I am setting a Timer, so it runs Twice a day (the times listed are for testing)

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Application.OnTime TimeValue("16:49:00"), "MyMacro"
  Application.OnTime TimeValue("16:45:00"), "MyMacro"
End Sub
```

The following script then Copies a range of Cells on Sheet1 and PasteSpecial their Values (to remove formulas) into the next empty row in Sheet2.

I have tried to clear the clipboard using the command `Application.CutCopyMode = False` at the end of the script, but when that didn't work, I put another one at the start.

```
Sub MyMacro()
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:R14").Copy
  Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial _
      Paste:=xlPasteValues
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

When it runs at 16:49, the data for 16:45 is pasted into Sheet2, instead of the new data.

---

**EDIT**

The OnTime doesn't seem to have any affect on the problem. It happens just by (F5) Running the My_Macro code on it's own.

I get the same problem running this code provided by Peter. Which I believe means that it's not a clipboard problem?

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MyMacro()
Dim srcSheet As Worksheet
Dim srcData As Range
Set srcSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set srcData = srcSheet.Range("A2:R14")

Dim dstSheet As Worksheet
Dim dstData As Range
Set dstSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

'--- this makes sure the destination range is the same size as
'    the source range
Set dstData = dstSheet.Range("A2").Resize(srcData.Rows.Count, srcData.Columns.Count)

'--- this is where the copy happens...
'    each of these ranges are not a single cell, but an area
'    so it copies all of the data from the source to the destination
dstData.Value = srcData.Value

End Sub
```

---

**EDIT 2**

CORRECTION... So, it appears, the other columns of data are actually being copied correctly. 
I have a column with the formula NOW() to give a TimeStamp to the data that gets copied. It's the column with the NOW() that isn't updating on each Run of the script. The TimeStamp column time is the previous time, but the other data is changing. For some reason the NOW() column isn't being properly copied over?

For instance:

*Sheet1* (original)

TimeStamp says 10:06

Column B says '30'

*Sheet2* (copy)

TimeStamp says 10:06

Column B says '30'

***The script runs again at 10:10*** ---------------

*Sheet1* (original)

TimeStamp says 10:10

Column B says '36'

*Sheet2* (copy)

TimeStamp says 10:**06**

Column B says '36'

Comment: Maybe force the workbook to recalculate before running the code or refresh any data sources?  `Application.CalculateFullRebuild` or `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll` for example.

Comment: Adding `Application.CalculateFullRebuild` worked perfectly! Thanks a lot Darren! If you make an answer I'll mark it as the solution. :) Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Application.CalculateFullRebuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-calculatefullrebuild-method-excel) will force a full calculation of all formula and a rebuild of all dependencies in the workbook.
This may be a bit overkill for what you need though; there's also [Application.Calculate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-calculate-method-excel) and [Application.CalculateFull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-calculatefull-method-excel).

[What is the difference between Application.Calculate and Application.CalculateFull?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37459903/what-is-the-difference-between-application-calculate-and-application-calculatefu)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to copy/paste, just make a direct copy of the range like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MyMacro()
    Dim srcSheet As Worksheet
    Dim srcData As Range
    Set srcSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set srcData = srcSheet.Range("e13:H20")

    Dim dstSheet As Worksheet
    Dim dstData As Range
    Set dstSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    '--- this makes sure the destination range is the same size as
    '    the source range
    Set dstData = dstSheet.Range("A1").Resize(srcData.Rows.Count, srcData.Columns.Count)

    '--- this is where the copy happens...
    '    each of these ranges are not a single cell, but an area
    '    so it copies all of the data from the source to the destination
    dstData.Value = srcData.Value

End Sub
```

The main difference between this technique and copy/paste is that copy/paste uses the clipboard and copies both data AND formatting, whereas the code example above only copies the data.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, when I use the above code I am getting the same problem. The previous data is being inserted in the cells, instead of the current. For instance, I have a column with the current TimeStamp of =NOW() in it. I press F5 to Run this script at 9:52. The 9:52 data shows up in Sheet2. I wait a couple of minutes and Run the script at 9:55. Instead of the 9:55 data, I get a repeat of the 9:52 data. If I Run the script again, suddenly the 9:55 data shows. It's constantly inputting the previous data every time the script runs.

Comment: CORRECTION... So, it appears, the other columns of data are actually being copied correctly. It's the column with the NOW() that isn't updating on each run of the script. The TimeStamp column time is the previous time, but the other data is changing. For some reason the NOW() column isn't being properly copied over?