# Application.Calculate Method doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba

I have a complex Excel with lot of tables and formulas.
I stop and resume calculations via VBA code:

Turn OFF calculations:

```
ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

Turn ON calculations:

```
ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.Calculate 'This line calculates all open books and is not strictly necessary.
```

But still the cells are not calculated.
**They are only calculated when I edit each cell with double click and hit Enter (one by one!).**

The code doesn't give me any errors and works perfectly on simple books.

Comment: Have you tried `Application.CalculateFull` or `Application.CalculateFullRebuild` ?

Comment: You don't need to set Calculation to xlCalculateAutomatic to use .Calculate btw.
As for CalculateFull and CalculateFullRebuild, if your file is as extensive as you say, try CalculateFull first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37461126/19353309

Comment: To explain why those aren't working:  `.Calculation = xlManual // xlAutomatic` toggles on/off automatic calculations for the application, which does not trigger events or imply volatility to begin calculating; by using `.Calculate` you should begin calculating uncalculated items.  [See this link](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsh.htm).  Others have already replied with the answer for what would work.

Comment: I think I have the solution: if I remove EnableCalculation lines it works perfectly. It seems that EnableCalculation have some bug. If I use only Calculation xlManual / xlAutomatic, it works good!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is "EnableCalculation" method.
If I remove it, then the book works perfect. So simply toggle ON/OFF calculations with xlAutomatic/xlManual, like this:

Turn OFF calculations:

`Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`

Turn ON calculations:

`Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic`